# TextView ShadowLayer being Clipped when Using WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, textview, ondraw

It's been a while since I've posted and I've read many posts to try to resolve my issue but I just can't seem to figure it out.
I am missing something and I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

In this example I have a TextView inside a Linear Layout with the LayoutParams set to MATCH_PARENT.
If I use WRAP_CONTENT with the TextView the Shadow is being clipped, even if I use Padding.
If I set the TextView to MATCH_PARENT the shadow isn't clipped.

TextView WRAP_CONTENT No Padding:
[image: TextView WRAP_CONTENT No Padding]

TextView WRAP_CONTENT with Padding
[image: Textview WRAP_CONTENT with Padding]

TextView MATCH_PARENT:
[image: TextView MATCH_PARENT]

I've even tried it with 
ll.setClipToPadding(false);
ll.setClipChildren(false);

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything, unfortunately. This seems to be a bug with how TextView measures italic text. It's a problem even without shadows.

[image]

You'd have to subclass `TextView` (or AppCompatTextView) and define custom measuring behavior to work around this.

If you don't want to bother with that, the consensus "best" answer is to add a non-breaking space to the end of your text in order to increase the measured size of the text. Unfortunately, this often adds more space than you really want.

[image]

Incidentally, `android:clipToPadding` is only an attribute on `ViewGroup`, which is why it doesn't do anything when you apply it to a `TextView` (it is simply ignored, like any other unknown attribute).

Comment: I played around with adding a space before and after the text and for smaller text sizes it works fine. Once you start using a large text size, as you stated, it consumes way to much real estate. Note: I was using .setClipToPadding and .setClipChildren on the LinearLayout which is the Parent View of the TextView.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood about your clipping strategy. Unfortunately, it is the TextView doing the clipping, so any clip attributes you set on the parent won't do anything in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably really bad practice but I went with the following:

```
tv.setHeight(tv.getHeight() + tv.getPaddingTop() + tv.getPaddingBottom());
tv.setWidth(tv.getWidth() + tv.getPaddingLeft() + tv.getPaddingRight());
tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Thanks Again Ben for helping me!